# Oozie job fails in Amazon EMR com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, hue

I'm building a job in the Hue workflow editor.  The data is located in s3 along and the workflow calls a simple Hive script.  I've tested the Hive script in the query editor and it works fine.  When I run the workflow I get this error:

```
Error starting action [MountFilesToHive]. ErrorType [ERROR], ErrorCode [RuntimeException], Message [RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:445)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help in getting the class resolved is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to put the missing jar in a lib directory in the workspace of the workflow? Or add it to the Hive Oozie sharelib.